# Appium cannot detect devices, but the terminal command does

Tags: android, linux, adb, appium

The error I'm currently receiving within the `Appium` logs is:

```
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb
kill-server
error: Error killing ADB server, going to see if it's online anyway
info: [debug] Getting connected devices...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb 
devices
info: [debug] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
info: [debug] executing cmd: /home/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb
kill-server
```

However, whilst this is running, if I open another Terminal window and type `adb devices`, it detected the two `Android` devices that are both online.

before Appium is executed, it even detects the phones within the logs:

```
DEBUG:devicelab.devices:Done. 2 Android and 0 Apple devices found
```

The user is the same, both for Appium and the Terminal commands.

Appium is installed on a linux box and we're using Python for the tests.

If you require further information / logs, please just let me know.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have you read this: http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.1.0/?ruby# ?

Comment: Check that you are using `adb` command from the same plase

Comment: I have read that documentation numerous times! Yes, it's being run from the same place. It's a global command also.

Comment: It may sound ridiculous but I couldn't connect to my emulator for some time. I noticed that there were a few adb processes in task manager (Win 7). I killed all these adb manually, restarted appium, restarted emulator and that's it.